# In C++, std::atomic generates race condition. But when using std::async, it generates race condition

Tags: c++, asynchronous, atomic

In C++, std::atomic generates race condition. But when using std::async, it generates race condition.

```cpp
std::atomic<int> k = 0;


int func()
{
    for (int i=0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        k++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    auto fut  = std::async(launch::async, func);
    auto fut2 = std::async(launch::async, func);

    cout<<"k : "<<k<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Results are not consistent.

```
2000000
1983702
1970595
...
```

But when using std::thread, it works fine.

As I know, std::atomic guarantees no race condition.
But Why is it so?

Comment: You are trying to read a value of `k` while the routines you started before reading it might not have finished.

Comment: you created racing condition in main().. I suppose with threads you mindlessly copied wait() call from an example.  but you easily could return end value inside of future, reading it would automatically wait for finish :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until your async call is finished.

```
    fut.wait();
    fut2.wait();
    std::cout<<"k : "<<k<<std::endl;
```

On my PC I got with your code always 0!